# How to run onclick event in asp.net from another button's javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Void button has a confirm box after receiving true, expecting running another button's click event
however, Void2_Button_Click not run, where is wrong?

```
protected void Void2_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // do something    
}


Void_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('Confirm to void?'); if (agree){document.getElementById('Void2_Button').click();}");
```

This question has not been solved yet, Who can answer?

Comment: Why do you run another button's click event programatically? Isn't it better to have both buttons trigger the same event handler in code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also have ordinary server side click for the first button, that will simply call the click event of the other button:

```
<asp:Button id="Void_Button" runat="server" Text="Void" OnClick="Void_Button_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm to void?');" />

protected void Void_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Void2_Button_Click(sender, e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the .ClientID for javascript. Try

```
Void_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('Confirm to void?'); if (agree){document.getElementById('"+Void2_Button.ClientID+"').click();}");
```

Comment: @Mathew are you adding this in `Page_Load` ?

Comment: yes, add in page load after if (!Page.IsPostBack), not trigger

Comment: if i do not do this, any other simple method to call function in asp .net cs code from javascript like above?

Comment: Can you try with out the if(!IsPostBack) condition in page_load?

Comment: tried, without !postback, not trigger, label not update and not server.transfer to another page, seems not run the function